# vector<string> or vector<shared_ptr<string>> in c++ 14

Tags: c++, c++11

In old c++ style, I always used `vector < shared_ptr < string> >` or `vector < string* >` to avoid memory copy when constructing a big `vector` which holds many `string` objects.

Since c++11, c++ has `rvalue` and `move` semantics; can I use `vector < string >` now?

I am using gcc 7.1.0 and clang 3.6 with the c++ 14 option.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you couldn't use `vector<string>` earlier. Were you worried about the overhead when the vector capacity was increased?

Comment: Sort of depends. How often do you keep a copy simultaneously in the vector and somewhere else with a lifetime that's potentially longer than the element in the vector? But `vector<shared_ptr<string>>` seems a little much, that's 3 dereferences for each access to a string

Comment: Yeah, you can use `std::vector<std::string>`. You can do a lot of things. And yes, since C++11, the vector will move its strings instead of copying, so you don't have to worry about expensive copies being made when resizing a vector.

Comment: if you use `std::vector<std::string>` then it means whenever you copy the vector to a new instance (`vector1 = vector2`), it will bring along its data, and you can not avoid copying there. The concept is completely different with `std::vector<std::string*>` which holds the pointer only. 
And rvalue and semantics only help you when moving the data around without unnecessary copying, but you can only have 1 `std::vector` holding these data at a time. To learn more about rvalue, i recommend this great post: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Answer (score 3):

There are several situations where using `vector<shared_ptr<string>>` or `vector<string*>` could help to optimize performance before C++11:

### When you add elements to a vector, e.g. calling push_back().

- Old behaviour: If vector capacity isn't large enough, the internal
  memory buffer will be reallocated and all the old objects will be
  copied to a new buffer.
- C++11 behaviour: If vector element type has non-throwing move constructor, then it is called instead of copy constructor. `std::string` has non-throwing move constructor, so in push_back() for `std::vector<string>` should be not slower then for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<string>>`.

### When returning a vector that is a local variable from a function

- Old behaviour: in case of returning a local variable from a function or method the result is copied. In some limited number of cases compiler is allowed to perform Return Value Optimisation - allocate the object directly on the stack on the caller.
- C++11 behaviour: if the return value is rvalue, the move constructor of the vector is called. This operation is actually very cheap (just swapping two pointers). So for int this case using `std::vector<string>` is appropriate too.

### Sharing strings between different vectors

If your intention is to return *copy* of the collection but not to *copy the elements* - that is the only way where `std::vector<shared_ptr<string>>` can still help. But in this case my advice is to share immutable objects between collections, i.e. use `std::vector<shared_ptr<const string>>`.